# Python output is different than what I need

Tags: python, printing, output

Hi guys I'm farely new to python and I need your help.

```
import sys, http.client

file = open('out.txt', 'w')
showlines = 50
npa = []

try:
     servername = sys.argv[1]
except:
    servername = 'localcallingguide.com' 
server = http.client.HTTPConnection(servername)

for i in range(1000):
    if i < 10:
        npa.append('00' + str(i))
    elif i >= 10 and i < 100:
        npa.append('0' + str(i))
    else:
        npa.append(str(i))

for i in range(len(npa)):
    filename = '/lca_rcdist.php?npa1=503&nxx1=745&npa2=503&nxx2=' + npa[i]
    server.putrequest('GET', filename)
    server.putheader('Accept', 'text/html')
    server.endheaders()
    reply = server.getresponse()

    if reply.status != 200:
        print('Error sending request', reply.status, reply.reason)
    else:
        data = reply.readlines()
        reply.close()
        for line in data[:showlines]:
            cLine = line.decode('utf-8')
            if '"ofrom">N<' in cLine:
                file.write('NXX ,' + npa[i])

file.close
```

With the above script, I get an output of "NXX, 503, NXX, 203, and so on, I need to hide the NXX from the output, any idea how to do that without removing the NXX for the script.

Thanks is advance!

Comment: Just an advice: you better give more (and more exact) detail if you want help. Your piece of code generates output like "NXX ,503" and not "NXX 503," for example. And what do you mean by you want to have another output, but don't want to change the script? Etc...

Comment: Question doesn't make sense. If you don't want NXX in the output, don't write it.

Comment: I updated the whole script, I did remove the NXX from the script, but the guy who I'm editing the scrip for is saying that I can't do that

Comment: "*I need your help.*" Welcome to Stack Overflow! While we do try to be helpful, StackOverflow isn't a support forum. It is a question-and-answer site. The general pattern is that you ask a question, and other readers answer it. I notice the lack of a question in your post. Please tell us what you have tried and specifically what isn't going right for you. Then ask us a question which, when answered, might move you toward your goal.

Comment: My question would be, is there a different way to print the output with all the information pulled from the localcallingguide.com without the leading NXX, I just need the area code separated but the commas in the output

Comment: If you can't change the script, then forget the script, and modify the output file with another script (e.g.: read, split by commas, write every second).

Comment: My best advice is to ask "the guy who I'm editing the scrip for" what I can do. Encourage him to explain to you all the constraints. Perhaps you could make a copy of the script and modify the copy. Perhaps you could write a new script from scratch. You'll discover these sorts of possibilities as you tease *all* of the requirements out of your customer.

Comment: P.s. `for i in range(len(npa)):` is a code smell. Prefer `for i in npa:` and update the loop body accordingly.

Comment: P.p.s: It might be easier and more reliable to use the XML interface: See http://localcallingguide.com/xmlquery.php and http://localcallingguide.com/xmlrcdist.php?npa1=416&nxx1=423&npa2=212&nxx2=733

Comment: I can modify the script but he's really picky how I can modify it I've tried file.write(',' + npa[i]) but that didn't fly with him...

Answer (score 2):

## If you *can* change the script, do this:

```
file.write(',' + npa[i])
```

## If you can't change this script do this:

If your script is called "example.py", then you could invoke it like this:

```
python example.py ; sed -i s/NXX//g out.txt
```

This will remove `NXX` from its output.

Comment: Second would be something like `sed s/NXX//g out.txt > new_out.txt`, because the "unchangeable" script writes its output to file.

Comment: Can I change the script using if, else statement that will aslo have the same effect?