# If, else statement output

Tags: python, if-statement

```
for i in range(len(npa)):
    filename = '/lca_rcdist.php?npa1=503&nxx1=745&npa2=503&nxx2=' + npa[i]
    reply = urllib.request.urlopen(servername + filename)

    if reply.status != 200:
        print('Error sending request', reply.status, reply.reason)
    else:
        data = reply.readlines()
        reply.close()
        for line in data[:showlines]:
            cLine = line.decode('utf-8')
            if '"ofrom">N<' in cLine:
                print('NXX ,' + npa[i])
```

The following output is `NXX,269NXX,298NXX,300NXX` and so on, is there a way to add if and else statement so that the output does not contain a comma and NXX in front of the first entry? example: `269NXX, 298NXX`? I'm new to this and still strugling with if and else statements on scripts like these. Any ifo on how to change the output using if, else statemnet will be appriciated.

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code. Correct indentation is critical in Python.

Comment: Just reverse the order of the `'NXX ,'` and the `npa[i]`? `print(npa[i] + 'NXX ,')` ?

Comment: @HenryKeiter Then you'll get an extra comma after the last element.

Comment: Also if I can hide NXX from the output that would be even better

Comment: @PaulZharyuk Doesn't your current output end with `300`, not `300NXX`?

Comment: How is this question different from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897845/python-output-is-different-than-what-i-need ?

Comment: I just need numbers seperated by commas, but I cannot have a comma in front of the first entry.

Comment: @Barmar No its 300NXX

Comment: How does that happen? You print `NXX,` _before_ each number, how do you get another `NXX` after the last one? Is there something you're not showing?

Comment: @BarmarNXX,269NXX,298NXX,300NXX,302NXX,304NXX,308NXX,315NXX,316NXX,322NXX,325NXX,338NXX,339NXX,354NXX,355NXX,361NXX,362NXX,363NXX,364NXX,365NXX,366

Comment: @Robᵩ Yea the question is similar to stackoverflow.com/questions/18897845/…  but I think I did not phrase the question correctly and I did not get the answer I needed, yet on this question your answer was spot on, I got the results I needed, thank you so much!

Answer (score 5):

Create a list and then use `str.join()`:

```
result = [] # NEW
for i in range(len(npa)):
    ... # blah, blah, same as your example, until
            if '"ofrom">N<' in cLine:
                result.append(npa[i])  # CHANGED
print (','.join(result))  #NEW
```

Comment: Fast, aren't we? ;) +1.

Comment: Doesn't this omit the `'NXX'` piece?

Comment: @HenryKeiter - Yes, as per request: "*Also if I can hide NXX from the output that would be even better*"

Comment: @Robᵩ Well I guess that would do it! I missed that comment.

Comment: Thanks you, This gives me the exact output I wanted!

Answer (score 2):

I dont know python but you can try this

declare a variable before the loop and set the value to 0 and then if the value of the variable is 0 in first if condition print without NXX and change the value of variable to 1 and put the else code with NXX.  Hope this helps.

```
flagfirst=0
for line in data[:showlines]:
    cLine = line.decode('utf-8')
    if '"ofrom">N<' in cLine:
        if flagfirst==0:
            print(npa[i]) 
            flagfirst=1
        else:
            print('NXX ,' + npa[i])
```

Comment: It's how we used to do it in the old days, before languages had built-in `join()` functions. BTW, I'd use `True` and `False` rather than `0` and `1`.

Comment: Can you try to move the if block where it says if flagfirst ==0 above the if '"ofrom">N .... statement and try. I think there flag is coming inside another if statement. 
`if flagfirst==0:
    if '"ofrom">N<' in cLine:

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit too complex than what you asked, but this is how I'd do it (I'm not saying it's the *correct* way -- I'm not sure actually).

I'd change the entire last for loop from this:

```
for line in data[:showlines]:
    cLine = line.decode('utf-8')
    if '"ofrom">N<' in cLine:
        print('NXX ,' + npa[i])
```

To this:

```
'NXX,'.join([npa[i] for l in data[:showlines] if '"ofrom">N<' in l.decode('utf-8')])
```

Answer (score 0):

`for i in range(len(something))` this is an anti-pattern in Python. Correcting your code for this, and a few other things:

```
results = []
for i in npa:
    qs = urllib.urlencode({'npa': i})
    filename = '/lca_rcdist.php?npa1=503&nxx1=745&npa2=503&{0}'.format(qs)
    url = '{0}{1}'.format(servername,filename)
    reply = urllib.request.urlopen(url)

    if reply.status != 200:
        print('Error sending request: {0.status} {0.reason}'.format(reply))
    else:
        data = reply.readlines()
        reply.close()
        for line in data[:showlines]:
            cLine = line.decode('utf-8')
            if '"ofrom">N<' in cLine:
                results.append('NXX{0}'.format(i))
```